# How to check if input file is empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Brand new to JS.
I am trying to check if the file input element is empty when submitting the form with jQuery/JavaScript.
I have gone through a bunch of solutions and nothing is working for me.  I am trying to avoid the `/c/fakepath` (unless there is no other option)

```
<input type="file" name="videoFile" id="videoUploadFile" />
```

This does not work:

```
var vidFile = $("#videoUploadFile").value;
```

The only way I can get the filename is if I use the following:

```
var vidFile = document.getElementById("videoUploadFile").files[0].name;
```

If there is no file available the code throws an error:

> cannot read property name of undefined

which makes sense because the array is not set. but I cannot figure out how to do any error handling with this.

How do I properly grab the file input element `videoUploadFile`, check if it's empty, throw an error message if it's empty?

Comment: Check `.files.length`?

Comment: you can also filter non-empty files if you have more than one on the form: ```var files = $('#formbody').find('input[type=file]').filter(function() {
   return $(this)[0].files.length > 0;
  });```

Comment: @PiotrKowalski
Great snippet but I would suggest to use let over var.
For more information about the differences between them see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Just check the length of [files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#Attributes) property, which is a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object contained on the input element

```
if( document.getElementById("videoUploadFile").files.length == 0 ){
    console.log("no files selected");
}
```

Comment: `( document.getElementById("videoUploadFile").files.length === 0 )`

Comment: See no purpose in third = sign here, except for IDE checks.

Answer (score 198):

Here is the jQuery version of it:

```
if ($('#videoUploadFile').get(0).files.length === 0) {
    console.log("No files selected.");
}
```

Comment: This answer is more appropriate as the OP asked for a JQuery solution.

Comment: `$('#videoUploadFile').get(0)` same as `$('#videoUploadFile')[0]` but perhaps `get()` does some sanity checks

Answer (score 29):

To check whether the input file is empty or not
by using the file length property, `index` should be specified like the following:

```
var vidFileLength = $("#videoUploadFile")[0].files.length;
if(vidFileLength === 0){
    alert("No file selected.");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party but I thought I'd add what I ended up using for this - which is to simply check if the file upload input does not contain a truthy value with the not operator & JQuery like so:

```
if (!$('#videoUploadFile').val()) {
  alert('Please Upload File');
}
```

Note that if this is in a form, you may also want to wrap it with the following handler to prevent the form from submitting:

```
$(document).on("click", ":submit", function (e) {

  if (!$('#videoUploadFile').val()) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Please Upload File');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Question: How to check File field is empty or not?

Answer: I have solved this issue using this Jquery code

```
//If your file Is Empty:
if ($('#videoUploadFile').val() == '') {
    $('#message').html("Please Attach File");
} else {
    alert('ok');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="file" id="videoUploadFile">
</form>
<br>
<br>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Further explanation on why this would work or what was wrong in the original question would help raise the quality of this answer.

Comment: @josh burgess  this answer was how to check  File is empty or not is another way to check your file when you submit form using jquery .

Comment: @JoshBurgess the OP is asking how to do this in jQuery. All other answers either use vanilla JS or a combo of JS and jQuery. This is the only one who uses jQuery exclusively. Maybe I'm picky, but I don't like to mix jQuery with vanilla JS unless I really have to.

Comment: @EduardLuca Answer is over two years old. It was flagged as low quality at the time. An explanation of the code is generally appreciated by the SO community, and the comment was meant as a helpful reminder to not just post code but to explain what the code is and why it works. Hope that helps clear things up.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $("#customFile").change(function() { 
    var fileName = $("#customFile").val();  

    if(fileName) { // returns true if the string is not empty   
        $('.picture-selected').addClass('disable-inputs'); 
        $('#btn').removeClass('disabled');   
    } else { // no file was selected 
      $('.picture-selected').removeClass('disable-inputs'); 
      $('#btn').addClass('disabled');
    }  
  });
```

Comment: I think you should add some comments on your post.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (data.name == '') {
   //file doesn't exist;
}
else {
   //file exist;
}
```