# Determine when an input of file contains a value

Tags: javascript, php, file

I have this application with a file input and a submit input. I want the submit input to be disabled until the file input has a value. How do I check this kind of information with JS? I tried adding a "required" to the file input, but it still doesn't work...

Should I just use PHP and check if $_FILE isset()?

Comment: Aren't you already doing that? Isn't your submit button disabled until it has a value?

Comment: *"The submit input is disabled until ..."* implies that the JS side already works. Please clarify.

Comment: @LeonAdler I worded the instructions wrong! Sorry...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if input file is empty in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793880/how-to-check-if-input-file-is-empty-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just use PHP and check if $_FILE isset()?

It is good practice to ensure that the server gets what is expected. So yes, additional checks for a file and eventual mischiefs should also be done on the server.

Here is an example of what you want on the client-side.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/up4vx65m/)

HTML

```
<form name="fileForm" onchange="changed()">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function changed() {
    var form = document.forms.fileForm;
    if(form.image.value.length > 0) {
        form.submit.removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        form.submit.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form name="form1">
          <input type="file" name="image" id="file_upload">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn_submit" >
        </form>

jQuery(document).ready(function()
{    
    /*To disable the button on load*/ 
    jQuery("#btn_submit").attr('disabled','disabled'); 


     jQuery("#file_upload").change(function()
    {       
       var file_value= jQuery(this).val();
      if(jQuery(this).val() === '')
      {                                          

        jQuery("#btn_submit").attr('disabled','disabled');                                         
      }
      else
      {
        jQuery("#btn_submit").removeAttr('disabled');
      }
  });
});
```