# Check if a file input has a file attached

Tags: jquery, input

Need to check if a `file input` has a file attached.

This code doesn't work:

```
<input type="file" name="logo">

if ($('input[type=file]').length > 0) {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        alert('Vide');
    }
    else {
        alert('Pas Vide');
    }
}
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

The `FileList` object has a `files` property whose length you can check. See [docs on FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).

*An object of this type is returned by the files property of the HTML `<input>` element*

This SO answer addresses this quite well [Possible duplicate ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793880/how-to-check-if-input-file-is-empty-in-jquery/25793915)

```js
$("input:file").change(function (){
if ($('input[type=file]').get(0).files.length > 0) {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        alert('Vide');
    }
    else {
        alert('Pas Vide');
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="logo">
```