# Javascript validation not working for checking file which is being uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

I am designing a form where a user has to upload a file. I am using javascript for client side validation if case the user has not uploaded a file, due to which the form will not be submitted. It is working for all the other fields in the form but not for the image file being upload. It is entering all the functions except for my image function

Here is an extract of the code:

```
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" onsubmit="return 
       validateForm()">


            <h3>Select image:
                <input type="file" name="fImg" id="fImge" accept="image/*">
            </h3>

            <input style="position: relative;top:-20px;left:10px; margin-bottom:5px ; 
           width:150px;height: 30px; float:right;background: #8B0000" type="submit" name="submit" 
           value="Save Changes">
      </form>


    <script>
    function validateForm()
    {


        if(!checkBlankImageById('fImge', 'Please choose an image'))
            return false;

        return true;
    }   //end validateForm()
    </script>
```

and in my external js file

```
    function checkBlankImageById(obj_id, obj_label)
    {
     alert('entered');
     if($("#" + obj_id).files.length ==0)
    {

       alert(obj_label);
       return false;
    }
     return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Source

[How to check if input file is empty in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793880/how-to-check-if-input-file-is-empty-in-jquery)

jQuery

```
if ($("#"+obj_id).get(0).files.length === 0) {
    console.log("No files selected.");
}
```

Vanilla Javscript

```
if( document.getElementById("videoUploadFile").files.length == 0 ){
    console.log("no files selected");
}
```

Explanation : You are trying vanilla javascript way of getting the length of the files from jQuery Object

Comment: but it does even enter my function for the blankfile check

Comment: Well in that case you defined a function in another scope and calling it in another.

Comment: Verify this by posting a screenshot of console tab of chrome dev tools

Comment: it was actually an issue with my browser