# input[type="file"] Determining if user hasn't chosen any files

Tags: javascript

When user clicks an input[type="file"] it shows them a popup to choose a file

User may choose one and click OK or click cancel

When they click OK - it's onChange event, great

When cancel - there is no event or I don't know about it

**So the question is:**

What event is fired when user clicks cancel or how to determine differently that no files have been chosen AFTER clicking cancel?

Comment: Examine the `files` property of the input element and check its length. Or the `value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if user selected a file for file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219/how-to-determine-if-user-selected-a-file-for-file-upload)

Comment: @ADyson when to examine? I don't have any events when the user clicks cancel

Comment: Probably makes sense to do it at the time you validate your form, before submitting it

Comment: I want to do it when the blur event fires, but the problem is that it fires right after opening the popup, not after you closing it by clicking cancel

Comment: This is 2024 and we still have no way to properly tell whether a file selection dialog window had no files chosen lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the user initiates the file upload by clicking on the file input, you can add an event listener to the browser window to see when it re-gains focus. Since the system dialog is blocking/modal, the window will only re-gain focus when the dialog is dismissed.

In the event handler function, you can check to see if the value of the input changed. At the end, remove the focus event handler so it doesn't trigger from normal alt-tab or window focus events:

```js
file.addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.onfocus = function () {
    console.log("The window was re-focused from the file input dialog");

    if (file.files.length === 0) {
      console.log("NO files were added");
    } else {
      console.log("Files were added");      
    }

    // Remove the handler
    window.onfocus = null;
  };
});
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file">
```

Comment: More than 4 years now and still usefull

Comment: This works to detect when the window closes, but doesn't always work to detect if no files were chosen, because my window is losing focus before the change event fires / before it detects that files were chosen, so "file.files.length" is giving 0

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `length` of the `files` property of the file selector node:

```
const input = document.querySelector ('input[type="file"]')
if(input.files.length === 0){
  //The user hasn't selected any files...
}
```

To detect changes, just add an event listener to the `change` event:

```
const input = document.querySelector ('input[type="file"]')
input.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
  if(input.files.length === 0){
    //Cancel clicked
  } else {
    //The user selected some files just now
  }
})
```

Comment: When should I do this? I don't have any events when user clicks cancel

Comment: Unfortunately, onChange event doesn't fire when you didn't choose anything and click cancel (Chrome, MacOS) But I suspect it works the same way everywhere