# Show fields only if file was uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form where I can upload a file if I want:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("Upload File", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="file" id="UploadedFile" name="upload" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I want when a file was uploaded these fields to appear:

```
<div id="optionalFields">

    <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
     </div>

    //other fields
</div>
```

I think Javascript is needed but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: You can create a JS event that triggers when the element with id `UploadedFile` is clicked, and display the element with id `optionalFields`.  Have you done any research or made any attempts to resolve this issue yourself?

Comment: I am not familiar with JS and I tought a simple solution would fit my need. After searching online I only found solutions that I don't understand so I came here for a straight answer directly on my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the optional fields:

```
//hide the optional fields on page load
document.getElementById("optionalFields").style.display = 'none';
//when the file upload input is clicked, show the optional fields
document.getElementById('UploadedFile').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('optionalFields').style.display='block';
};
```

Note: the above code is a simple demo of how to display the optional fields when the file upload input is clicked.  It does not include any kind of validation that the user actually selected a file to upload.  Nor does it contain validations that the file upload was successful.

Comment: How do I verify that the user actually selected a file and not clicked on the upload button and then canceled?

Comment: @blanos14 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219/how-to-determine-if-user-selected-a-file-for-file-upload

Comment: @blanos14 : and in that case, you'll want to look for the `change` event, not the `click` event.