# How i can update the image url if user select new file other wise image url not update in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cloudinary

**I'm creating a book project where i'm saving the books images into the cloudinary and there url's saving into the mongodb database which are working well.But i'm facing issue during the updation of a book when i update my book then the url of book is not updated and console giving me error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') where i want to update the url with new one url of image but its not working Please any one can solve this**

*this is my update.js code*

```
module.exports.updateBook = async (req, res) => {
try {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const book = req.body;
  const singleBook = await Book.findById(id);
  // Delete Prvious Url From the Cloudinary and Reset It to the new ..
  cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(singleBook.image[0].filename);
  book.image = req.files.map((f) => ({
   url: f.path,
   filename: f.filename,
  }));
   console.log("Single Book ===", singleBook);
   const updateBook = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    { $set: book },
    { new: true }
   );
  if (updateBook) {
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ success: true, message: "Book Updated Successfully!" });
  } else {
     res.status(400).json({
     success: false,
     message: "Book Not Updated There Is an error!",
   });
  }
 } catch (err) {
   console.log("** Error In Update Book **", err.message);
 }
};
```

*this is my route handler*

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const book = require("../controller/book");
const authenticated = require("../middleware/verifyToken");
const multer = require("multer");
const { storage } = require("../cloudinary");
const upload = multer({ storage });

// Update Book By ID
router.route("/:id").put(authenticated, upload.array("image"), book.updateBook);
module.exports = router;
```

*this is my reactjs update method*

```
  const formik = useFormik({
   initialValues: {
    title: book?.title,
    author: book?.author,
    price: book?.price,
    description: book?.description,
    image: book?.image[0].url,
  },
validationSchema: validationSchema,
enableReinitialize: true,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("title", values.title);
      formData.append("price", values.price);
      formData.append("description", values.description);
      formData.append("author", values.author);
      formData.append("image", values.image);
      Axios.put(`${Base_URL}/book/${id}`, values, {
        headers: {
        Authorization: authHeader(),
       },
      })
       .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.success) {
          message = res.data.message;
          setAlertContentupdate(message);
          setAlertupdate(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
           handleClose();
             navigate(`/book/${id}`);
           getBook();
           console.log("Response == ", res.data.message);
          }, 3000);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error ====", err.message);
       });
     },
```

*this is my jsx code for updating book*

```
 <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            name="title"
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            label="Book Title"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
            value={formik.values.title}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            error={formik.touched.title && Boolean(formik.errors.title)}
            helperText={formik.touched.title && formik.errors.title}
          />
          <TextField
            name="author"
            margin="dense"
            label="Book Author"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
            value={formik.values.author}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            error={formik.touched.author && Boolean(formik.errors.title)}
            helperText={formik.touched.author && formik.errors.author}
          />
          {/* File Input Field */}
          {/* Picture Input */}
          <input
            type="file"
            name="image"
            accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg"
            onChange={(e) => {
              formik.setFieldValue("image", e.target.files[0]);
            }}
          />
          {formik.touched.image && formik.errors.image ? (
            <div style={{ color: "#e53935", fontSize: "12px" }}>
              {formik.errors.image}
            </div>
          ) : null}
          {/* Price Input Field */}
          <TextField
            name="price"
            margin="dense"
            label="Book Price"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
            value={formik.values.price}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            error={formik.touched.price && Boolean(formik.errors.price)}
            helperText={formik.touched.price && formik.errors.price}
          />
          <TextField
            name="description"
            margin="dense"
            label="Book Description"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
            value={formik.values.description}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            error={
              formik.touched.description &&
              Boolean(formik.errors.description)
            }
            helperText={
              formik.touched.description && formik.errors.description
            }
          />
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
            <Button type="submit">Update</Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </form>
```

**In formik i'm getting the book data from back end api's and putting into the formik initial values But Problem is that when i clicked on the update button then the backend compiler giving me this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Please any one can solve this thanks in advance**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this line looks like the issue for me:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(singleBook.image[0].filename);
```

Using this is actually deleting your asset so you are probably want to just update it using the explicit API. See https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#explicit

So maybe something like:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.explicit(singleBook.image[0].filename);
```

Let me know if this helps?

Comment: thanks for your precious answer but my problem is that when i not select any file in my update form and update others book items then my image url destroy and nothing shown on my home screen

Comment: is there any way if i not select any image in my update form then my previous image still same as it was

Comment: In that case, you should probably add a check in your react.js file to validate whether the user selected a file so the `Update` should only execute when a file is selected. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219/how-to-determine-if-user-selected-a-file-for-file-upload, hope this helps.

Comment: Good it's right